# Can two nodes have same URL using Pathauto?

Tags: uri

I know that Drupal allows same url for multiple nodes.
But I've a scenario: a registered user creates and submits an article as an unpublished node and assigned an URL by pathauto based on its title. 
At the same time another user creates an article with same title in unpublished form. Will it too have same url?

I'll not "publish" those nodes anytime. I'll (as an admin) simply create a new node and copy paste contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a registered user creates and submits an article as an unpublished node and assigned an URL by pathauto based on its title. At the same time another user creates an article with same title in unpublished form. Will it too have same url?

No. pathauto by default will append a number to the end of the URL to differentiate between them.

Comment: Thanks but my question is little different than you've answered

Comment: @AgA I can't see how I've missed the question, but if I have, please clarify the question, don't just tell me I've answered the wrong one!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but Drupal does not allow same URL for multiple nodes.

Comment: No it does. For example in views we can setup same url for different views that is one for anonymous and another for registered.

Comment: It does, you can have the same alias in different languages (url_alias table).

Comment: AgA is talking about Views, not nodes. Anyway, Drupal does not allow same URL for multiple views either. The answer to his question is no, two newly created nodes by two different users will NEVER have same URL. Bart's got a bit of a point there, even though you can hardly consider translation a completely separate node.