# Displaying a text field for the user to embed media, and then enabling rating (fivestar) for that content; listing all of them as separate writings

Tags: 6, forms, webforms, rating, nodes

On a given site's page, which is supplied with the "*casting*" URL alias, I would like to show some embedded videos with a description field, which users have uploaded (embedded) via a simple text field that **[Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield)** processed. These would appear as separate writings, signing the user who uploaded this stuff.
There would also be a rating/voting opportunity (fivestar, thumbs up/down, etc.) with the help of **[Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) or [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar)** module (which one do you suggest?!) to let users vote for the embedded video.

When someone logs in, I would like to **show the form which helps embedding** (or a link to this form) at the top of the page, and below that, there would be the embedded media from the different users.
So the form would be as simple as that: containing a **text field**, in which e.g. Youtube URLs could be copied (it would be processed by Embedded Media Field module) and a **description** textarea to write about the embedded stuff.
The result output would contain these: the embedded media, the description, who this post created and when, and a rating/voting opportunity (five stars, etc.).

How could I do that? What do you suggest for creating a form like that?
Maybe it's not too difficult, but I didn't find the perfect solution, and I couldn't restrict content types to these fields (and with the help of [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) I couldn't add a field of Embedded Media Field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just let your users create a node with this field and a fivestar widget and then you use `node_view()` to display these nodes in your page.

**Updated:**
To embed the node form in a page, have a look at [Embedding CCK content type create form in your page](http://drupal.org/node/464906), then create a block and put this code in it (select the php format - you have to activate the php filter module first):

```
if(!function_exists("node_object_prepare")) {
  include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'node') . '/node.pages.inc');
}
print node_add('store_review');  //put the content type machine name here.
```

Then on another page you create a view to retrieve the listing of your videos.

You can also have a look at the [Blockify](http://drupal.org/project/blockify) module it may be useful to embed the node form (I'm not sure it'll do the job but can be easy if you're not comfortable with embedding PHP code in a block).

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. I would add that you can create a views block and put it in a "content" region (if your theme has one, I know Garland does) to have the media from other users show up on the node add form.

Comment: @rocketeerbkw, tostinni: thanks for your answers, I forgot to mention that I already created a content type called "Casting video" (concept is that users could embed their videos from external sources, and these could be rated), BUT it has too many fields, look at the pic: http://goo.gl/VyGnm - the field "Embedding video" is OK, BUT besides I would only need max. two text input fields (and not a textarea), and hide "Menu settings", "Input format", "Revision information", "File attachments", etc... How can I do this? And how can I use node_view() on a given node? Sorry, I'm new to this...

Comment: @Sk8erPeter your node has too many fields because you're connected as admin, try to connect yourself with a normal user it will be much more simple. To disable the textarea (aka body), go to the edit page for your content type and delete the label for "body".

Comment: @tostinni: wow, didn't think it's that simple as deleting the "Body" label in "Submission form settings" and not to login as an admin... :D Thanks! That's great, but I still have questions (after these I'll accept your answer :) ): how can I configure the page which has the "casting" alias so that this form should appear on the top of this page (it could be a panel or I don't know how it should be done) JUST FOR LOGGED IN USERS, and after that, all of the uploaded embedded videos would be listed one after another (with a pager at the bottom of the page)? If user isn't logged in, just the list.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter I updated my answer

Comment: @tostini: thanks, it seems to be good, but I have another problem - I made the following changes: I made a View as suggested in this answer depending on different rules: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8718/change-node-content-after-logging-in-under-the-same-url-alias-showing-other-cont/8720#8720, because I would like to show the upload form only to authenticated users. I set a "Header" for this View, in which I selected "PHP code" input type, and put your code into it. It's OK, it displays the form, BUT elements of the form appear in every nodes!How can I display it only at the top?

Comment: OK, finally I solved it with a Panel: I created a custom layout with some rows in it; in the top row I pasted your code customized to my own stuffs, checking whether user is logged in with user_is_logged_in() function. If user is logged in, I display the form, otherwise I display the text "Log in or register to....." etc. In the row under the form I display my view I created before with the embedded media and the fivestar widget. That solved my problem! Thank you!